# Why doesn't php recognize this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a simple mysql query in php , but it doesn't run . It says that B.ISBN etc. are undefined indexes. Why is that ? Doesn't php recognize the AS (something) of mysql ? I have edited to add the whole code of the file, sorry for any misunderstanding

```
<?php include 'dbconfig.php';  $Title = $_GET['Title'];?>
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUCLIC "-//W3C//DTDHTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mytable.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</HEAD>
<TABLE class="minimalistBlack">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th> ISBN </th>
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Number of Pages </th>
        <th> Publisher Name </th>
        <th> Copy Number </th>
        <th> Shelf </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
            $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","library");
            mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

            if ($conn -> connect_error){
                die("Conenction failed:". $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $sql="SELECT B.ISBN,B.Title,B.numpages,B.pubName,C.copyNr,C.shelf
            FROM book AS B
            INNER JOIN copies as C
               ON B.ISBN=C.ISBN";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows>0){
                while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['B.ISBN']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['B.Title']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['B.numpages']."</td>";    
                    echo "<td>".$row['B.pubName']."</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>".$row['C.copyNr']."</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>".$row['C.shelf']."</td>";                   
                }
                echo "</TABLE>";
            }
            else { echo "0 result"; }
            $conn->close();
         ?>
    </TABLE>
</HTML>
```

Comment: your sql query gives output in phpmyadmin?

Comment: The variable `$Title` is undefined. (The query is also not safe against sql injections)

Comment: @MohitKumar yes

Comment: @odan I have used a get statement in the start of the file , so it is defined

Comment: Try to leave the table aliases in the `echo`s away. `echo "<td>" . $row['ISBN'] . "</td>";` instead of `echo "<td>" . $row['B.ISBN'] . "</td>";`, etc....

Comment: @stickybit comment of the year!

Comment: @thriteenchess which of these answers solved your problem. Please accept that answer.

Comment: @Pie actually sticky bit's comment solved it with a code from a provided answer , which all are pretty much the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT B.ISBN,B.Title,B.numpages,B.pubName,C.copyNr,C.shelf
FROM book AS B
INNER JOIN copies as C
   ON B.ISBN=C.ISBN
WHERE B.Title='$Title'";
```

Comment: but what about the title?

Comment: Edited, but I don't see `$Title` defined anywhere.

Comment: I edited the post to include the whole code , sorry for any misunderstanding

Answer (score -1):

You can use this nomenclature to name tables.

```
SELECT B.ISBN,B.Title,B.numpages,B.pubName FROM book B JOIN copies C WHERE B.ISBN=C.ISBN AND B.Title = '+$title;
```

Comment: this seems to partially work , however I get this error : Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\wamp\www\search_query.php on line 31

Comment: @thriteenchess I personally recommend you to prove the query directly against the databes. If you're using phpmyadmin for example, try to execute the query manually and edit it till it Works. After that put the same query in the php script. By that you can confirm that the query works. It gives you that error because $result is not set (the query is not correct).

Comment: the query succesfully run in phpmyadmin

Comment: then echo the query saved in $sql to see if its the same as the one you put in phpmyadmin (maybe is some simple string error).

Answer (score -1):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT B.ISBN, 
     B.Title, 
     B.numpages, 
     B.pubName, 
     C.copyNr, 
     C.shelf 
FROM book as B
LEFT JOIN copies AS C ON B.ISBN=C.ISBN
WHERE B.Title = '”.$Title.”’”
```

Comment: You can also swap left join for inner join depending on you situation

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql="SELECT B.ISBN,B.Title,B.numpages,B.pubName,C.copyNr,C.shelf
FROM book AS B
INNER JOIN copies as C
   ON B.ISBN=C.ISBN
WHERE B.Title = '".$Title."'";
```